# Shift list entries in for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to use use two entries within a for loop and have them shift over each iteration.

My list looks like this:    `change_loc = [0, 380, 499, 1742, 1862, 2938]` and it's computed in the first lines of the following function:

```
def average_points(sal_data):
    """Find the changing indexes then average 5 last and first points."""
    data = copy.deepcopy(sal_data)
    start = 0
    end = data.index[-1]
    change_loc.insert(0, start)
    change_loc.append(end)
    for change in change_loc:
        first = (data['sal'][0:380].iloc[-5:])
        last= data['sal'][380:499].iloc[:5]
        mean = first.append(last).mean()
    return pd.Series({
        "average_points": mean
        })
```

In the function, I would like the for loop to shift from two points to the next two. For example, as it currently is, the function uses `[0:380]` and `[380:499]`. Next I would like for it to use `[380:499]` and `[499:1782]`, etc. Any idea how to do this? Do I need a counter?

The goal of this function is to grab the last 5 and first 5 entries of a section of the data and then grab the mean of these 10 points.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you basically trying to compute `data['sal'][375:385].mean()` for the first iteration?

Comment: Yes, basically - the thing is, the list is based off another part of the code. My data is composed of salinity data taken by two separate pumps and `change_loc` is a list of indexes where the pump switches. I want to take the last 5 datapoints of pump A and first 5 datapoints of pump B, and average them. Pump A and pump B are differentiated in a separate column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this code:

```
change_loc =  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
for i in range(1, len(change_loc) -1):
    first =  [change_loc[i-1], change_loc[i]]
    last = [change_loc[i], change_loc[i+1]]
    print('loop {}: {}, {}'.format(i, first, last))
```

Result:

```
loop 1: [1, 2], [2, 3]
loop 2: [2, 3], [3, 4]
loop 3: [3, 4], [4, 5]
loop 4: [4, 5], [5, 6]
loop 5: [5, 6], [6, 7]
```

Comment: Thanks! I just had to change ```[change_loc[i-1], change_loc[i]]``` to ```[change_loc[i-1]:change_loc[i]]``` and it's not working wonderfully :)